# How long should it take for a woman to return to her pre pregnancy weight

Tags: obstetrics, body-weight

How long should it take for a woman to return to her pre pregnancy weight after giving birth?

- She is at a healthy weight
- No other issues

This would probably be some sought of range and my guess is straight away is too short

Answer (score 1):

Dr Julie Wray, of Salford University, interviewed women two to three weeks, three months and six to seven months after they had given birth to gain a unique insight into postnatal recovery.

She concluded that it takes a year to recover from childbirth. Her study also revealed significant dissatisfaction amongst new mothers with postnatal services.

In the first few days after you give birth, you'll lose weight quickly, as the extra water you carried during late pregnancy is passed out in your wee and sweat. You will lose more weight as the amount of circulating blood returns to normal levels, and your uterus gets smaller. But after this, weight loss tends to slow down.

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2102517/Women-need-year-recover-childbirth-study-finds.html

http://www.babycentre.co.uk/a536333/your-body-after-the-birth